# How can I join two tables such that all rows of one are duplicated for all rows of another?

Tags: sql, database, join

For example, let's say I have the following two tables:

Table1:

```
Id
----
1
2
```

Table2:

```
Month
------
Jan
Feb
```

And I want to combine them using an SQL query to form the following output:

```
Id        Month
----      -------
1         Jan
1         Feb
2         Jan
2         Feb
```

Is there a way to do this using a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is "cross join":

```
select *
from t1 cross join j2
```

There is no "on" clause for a cross join.  You can do the same thing just using a comma, but this is ancient (and hopefully one day deprecated) SQL syntax.  The cross join is the right way to go.

Comment: Marked as answer for using the explicit cross join, which is a little more clear.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a cartesian product and it will occur if you don't specify a join condition. Be careful though!

```
SELECT ids.Id, months.Month
FROM ids, months
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make an outer join between this 2 tables